# Store html values of divs with a class and recall them later with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have several div's that have their html modified during the life of the page.  How do i store their original content as defaults so that i can recall them with a reset button?  They all share a same class but each has a unique class that begins with "message-".  Since the message class is dynamic I have no way of knowing what it is in advance. It may be possible to switch the message- to an ID if thats a better approach.

```
<div class="foo message-heading">some html</div>
<div class="foo message-body">some other html</div>
<div class="foo message-footer">some more html</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the default value in the element's data on dom ready like this

```
$(function() {
    $(".class-that-should-have-default-content").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.data("default-content", $this.html());
    }
}
```

and then reset it like this when you want:

```
$(element).html($(element).data("default-content"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using HTML5 you can store the original values using a`data-x` attribute.

HTML

```
<div class="foo message-heading" data-default="some html">some html</div>
<div class="foo message-body" data-default="some other html">some other html</div>
<div class="foo message-footer" data-default="some more html">some more html</div>
```

jQuery

```
$("#btnReset").click(function() {
    $(".foo").each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).data("default"));
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t6a7e/)

Comment: I originally intended to do this but was hoping there was a way to just store the existing html to cut down on maintenance.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is the perfect use case for [`jQuery.data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/), which allows you to attach data to a DOM element.

### Example code

```
var element = $('.foo .message-body');
// Save
$.data(element, 'default-value', element.html());

// Load
element.html($.data(element, 'default-value'));
```

Comment: [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) is easier to use than [`jQuery.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/), in this case.

Comment: data was just what I needed.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean *store the entire tags with their HTML* I would do something like this:

```
$(".foo").each(function () {
    $(this).data("original", $(this).clone());
});
```

...and then reset them like this:

```
$(".foo").each(function () {
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).data("original"));
});
```

Comment: I was just looking for the html.  Thanks for your time.  I got the answer i needed.